# When launching an iOS simulator it closes straight away but still runs in the background

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I try to run a project (even a default single view app) in Xcode 10.2 (also occoured on Xcode 10.3 and beta 11 build 3) the simulator launches but then closes but Xcode still thinks it's running (looks like it is running headless). Any ideas on how I can see the simulator?

I have tried the following so far but the only time I can see the Simulator is on its first launch after that it disappears after launching.

1. Uninstalling and re-installing Xcode (making sure to delete all related directories and doing a system restart)
2. Adding and removing simulators from `window -> Devices and simulators` from within Xcode
3. Tried clearing the simulator cache `xcrun simctl erase all`
4. Tried running the following `sudo killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`
5. Clearing Derived data `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Another thing I noticed is if I run: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator` I get the following error:

```
Bus error: 10
```

But if I run: `sudo/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator` the Simulator launches fine.

Thanks for any help.